# Not Getting Correct Print Output with Linked Lists

Tags: python, list, linked-list, nodes

This is currently the function I'm working with. Its a linked list using the nodes class. Here's the [implementation of it from my textbook](https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/BasicDS/ImplementinganUnorderedListLinkedLists.html). However when I try to print I get this output.

<**main**.Node object at 0x000001C1A21E5470> <**main**.Node object at 0x000001C1A21E5438> <**main**.Node object at 0x000001C1A21E54A8> <**main**.Node object at 0x000001C1A21E5400>

I read that using a __repr__ could help print, however it did not work for me when I implemented it.

```
def copyList(self):
    links = LinkedList()
    current = self.head
    while current.getNext() != None:
        links.addLast(current)
        current= current.getNext()
    links.addLast(current.getData())
    return links
```

The function is called like this

```
list2=list1.copyList()
print(list2)
```

The **repr** function I attempted

```
def __repr__(self):
    string=''
    current = self.head
    if current != None:
        string += str(current.getData())
        current = current.getNext()
        counter=2
        while current:
            string += " "+str(current.getData())
            current = current.getNext()
            if counter>9:
                string=string+'\n'
                counter=0
            counter=counter+1
    return string
```

Comment: What does `current.getData()` return?

Comment: It returns the string value of the node

Answer (score 0):

It seems I misunderstood your question.

I think the problem is in your `copyList` function. It should be:

```
def copyList(self):
    links = LinkedList()
    current = self.head
    while current.getNext() != None:
        links.addLast(current.getData())
        current = current.getNext()
    links.addLast(current.getData())
    return links
```

You used `links.addLast(current)`. Need to see the implementation of `addLast()` method for more details.

Comment: I have both a \__str__ and \__repr__ in my code right now. Should I get rid of one? I was using \__str__ only before and it didn't seem to work either. Both \__str__ and \__repr__ have the same code

Comment: @pythonHelp sorry, I might misunderstand your question. I edited my answer. Hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks, this actually fixed my problem. I was using nodes as parameters as functions when it should have been strings. Thanks!

Comment: @pythonHelp glad to help. you can accept this answer:)